# Dismiss DialogFragment after it recreate after killed on low memory

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

My `DialogFragment` have a listener which I pass from some `Activity` or `Fragment`.
So with current code below, if I open this dialog then go to background and put it for a long time or device on low memory, the dialog will be clear.
Then when I open app again and press at `btnOK`, I will get `NullPointerException` because `listener` = null

```
public class Dialog extends DialogFragment {
    DialogListener listener;

    public static Dialog newInstance(String title, DialogListener listener) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        Dialog fragment = new Dialog();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        fragment.setListener(listener);
        return fragment;
    }

    public void setListener(DialogListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(savedInstanceState != null){
            dismiss();
        }
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_view, container);
        Button btnOK = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnOK);

        btnOK.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listener.onClick();
                dismiss();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    interface DialogListener {
        void onClick();
    }
}
```

For prevent it, I will dismiss the DialogFragment when it recreated like.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if(savedInstanceState != null){
        dismiss();
    }
}
```

It work well in case fragment destroy and recreate but I don't know if does this solution work well for all case?  I dismiss the dialog inside `onCreate()` so I afraid that if in some case I don't handle user never can open the dialog.
Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can dismiss the dialog if the activity is getting destroyed.

Just add this inside your Dialog Fragment.

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    dismissAllowingStateLoss();
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

Comment: we can not do it. if we dismiss dialog inside onSaveInstanceState(...), we will get java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after onSaveInstanceState

Comment: It is not good practise, if you want to dismiss in `onSaveInstanceState()`, you could do it in `onPause()`, without allowing state loss

Answer (score 0):

The reason why `listener` is null is that you set it yourself using `setListener`. You can put this responsibility on Android by setting the listener in `onAttach` method.

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (!(context instanceof YourDialogListener)) {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.getClass() + " must implement "
                + YourDialogListener.class);
    }
    listener = (YourDialogListener) context;
}
```

and then in your activity

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements YourDialogListener {
    private void someMethodHandlingButtonOrMenuClick() {
        DialogFragment dialogFragment = new YourDialogFragment();
        dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), YourDialogFragment.class.getSimpleName());
    }
```